# Items not in repository

Tags: brother

Two library files are missing from my system and do not show up in the repository. They are needed to enable the scanner of my Brother MFC-845CW to scan.
They are:

libsane-brother2.so.1  and
libsane-smfp.so.1

How can I get them?

TIA

Comment: Those files do not exist in the official repositories. Maybe in some driver packages from the manufacturer? Where did you hear about them?

Comment: I think Debian. What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You might check:

http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadtop.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=mfc845cw_us

http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=eu_ot&lang=en&prod=mfc845cw_eu&os=128

https://support.brother.com/g/s/id/linux/en/faq_scn.html?c=us_ot&lang=en&comple=on&redirect=on

Google search for **Brother MFC-845CW ubuntu**.